# How to solve the covariances of single factor ANOVA?

Tags: statistics, regression, hypothesis-testing, anova

For a single factor experiment we have:
$$Y_{ij}=\mu+\epsilon_{ij} = \mu_i +\tau_i +\epsilon_{ij}$$,
where $\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.
To make things simpler lets say our experiment is balanced so $i=1,\cdots,k$ and $j=1,\cdots,n$.\
Now, say we have:

$$Cov(Y_{ij}-\bar{Y}_{i.},Y_{i'j'}-\bar{Y}_{i'.}) = Cov(Y_{ij},Y_{i'j'}) + \cdots + Cov(\bar{Y}_{i.},\bar{Y}_{i'.}).$$
Then I considered the cases $i=i',j=j'$ and so on.
I only got for $i=i',j=j'$, the covariance is $\frac{N-1}{N}\sigma^2$ and the rest of it is $0$. I'm not sure if its correct or not.